# Android add string to listview if cursor.getCount() returns zero

Tags: android, listview, cursor

I am performing some queries to a database and I'm showing the results on a `listView`.

This is done like this:

```
bd.open();
ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
Cursor proc = bd.getData(3,0,query);

MyAdapt cursorAdapter = new MyAdapt(this, proc,0);
listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

and `MyAdapt` is something like this:

```
public class MyAdapt extends CursorAdapter {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int n;

    public MyAdapt(Context context, Cursor c, int dbColumn) {
        super(context, c);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
        n = dbColumn;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            TextView fName = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            fName.setText(cursor.getString("Something returned by the cursor")));
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (context.getClass().getName().equals("something")) {
            final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.proclist, parent, false);
            return view;
        } else {
            final View view = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

When I perform a query that returns results, this is working ok and showing the results that I want.

If the query returns nothing, nothing Is shown on the `listView`.

In this case (where query returns nothing) I want to display the text `"Somenthing not found!"`.

This is what I've modified:

```
bd.open();
ListView listContent = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
Cursor proc = bd.getData(3,0,query);
if (proc.getCount()==0) {
    LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View layout = li.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null);
    TextView fName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    fName.setText(getString(R.string.notFound));
} else {
    MyAdapt cursorAdapter = new MyAdapt(this, proc,0);
    listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
}
```

This is not working and I don't understand why.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Following yours suggestions inside the `if statement` removed everything  and put this:

```
            View empty = findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
            TextView emptyText = (TextView)empty.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
            emptyText.setText(getString(R.string.notFound));
            listContent.setEmptyView(empty);
```

This is not working. It's giving me a `NullPointerException` on `emptyText.setText(getString(R.string.notFound));`

Wasn't this supposed to be like this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `proc.getCount()` instead of `procura.getCount()` ?

Comment: if bd(db?) is database object you should not close it because cursor need opened db connection ...

Comment: also you dont need to do all these to add a layout when empty, there is specifically a layout defined when the list is empty check the doc for [ListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Comment: @fiddler Sure it is. Lost in translation from my native language to English. Corrected that

Comment: @Selvin Ok. This was a mistake. Corrected that

Comment: @nandeesh Thanks. If tried to do like the link you provided me and updated my question. I'm getting an error that can't solve

Comment: android.R.id.empty will not be there in your xml. If you are setting it programmatically. Create one more xml and inflate it and you can use setEmptyView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should used the way @aprian told like this: Add the follow segment to your layout, and do nothing in your java code.

> ```
> <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"  
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
>     android:layout_marginTop="130px"  
>     android:textSize="25px"  
>     android:text="@+string/textview_text"/>
> ```

Update， you can also create a layout which contained a ListView named `@+id/android:list` and load it using `setContentView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center_horizontal">

 <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
 <TextView android:id="@+id/android:empty"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginTop="130px"
  android:textSize="25px"
  android:text="@+string/textview_text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I'm using this `android.R.id.listandroid.R.id.list` layout

Answer (score 1):

add a View with id `@android:id/empty` to your layout. it will shown whenever `ListView` is empty